# Using ProcessBuilder to make a jar file isn't completing

Tags: java, jar, cmd, processbuilder

I am trying to compile a jar file from within a Java program. When I run the code it starts to build the jar file and saves about 24k of it then the execution just seems to stop and wait (I am using Process.waitFor() and the program isn't finishing its execution). When I force the program to stop the size of the jar file jumps to about 45k. The jar should be about 1300k.

I tried creating a batch file and then calling the batch file with my `ProcessBuilder` but the same issue occurs. The batch file when run by itself works perfectly.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public static void buildJar() {

    List<String> jarCmdArgs = new ArrayList<>();
    jarCmdArgs.add("jar");
    jarCmdArgs.add("cvfM");
    jarCmdArgs.add(ROOT_DIRECTORY + File.separator + "my_jar.jar");
    jarCmdArgs.add(".");

//        jarCmdArgs.add("cmd.exe");
//        jarCmdArgs.add("/C");
//        jarCmdArgs.add(ROOT_DIRECTORY + File.separator + "make_jar.bat");

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(jarCmdArgs);
    pb.directory(new File(SRC_DIR_PATH));
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the contents of the batch file:

```
//cd to my working dir with all the files to put into the jar
jar cvfM my_jar.jar .
```

Comment: Have you printed out ROOT_DIRECTORY? Do you need a `/` after it?

Comment: oops I was playing around with the code and mustve made a change there and forgot to change it back. I fixed it but the issue is persisting.

Comment: Any error messages? Why not call `pb.inheritIO();` after creating your ProcessBuilder so that the error stream is redirected to the current process's stream?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok thats the strangest thing. I called pb.inheritIO() and now it is working fine...

Comment: hmmm.... go figure